# Disable mouse click and change pointer icon

Tags: python, linux

i want to make application that like [xtrlock](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xtrlock.1x.html) but i don't know how to disable the mouse click (mouse movement still allowed) and change cursor icon (with custom png)

my simple python code is :

```
while True:
  password = raw_input()
  if password == "password":
    exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically need to interface with some [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) and some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server). On Linux that could be [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). So you should use some [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) (and they usually provide some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)). Read more about [GTK](http://gtk.org/) & [Qt](http://qt.io/). Both are interfaced to Python, with [PyGTK](http://pygtk.org/) or [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro). Write first some simple GUI application (in PyGTK or PyQt) to understand the concepts.

BTW, `xtrlock` is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study its source code for inspiration.